# SetTimeout in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to trigger `setTimeout` in React.

I'm pretty new to React and was taking a look at the documentation & "tic-tac-toe" guide. I modified the code from the guide and I wanted to reset the state to initial values after 3 seconds from finding the winner of the game.

The only information I could find was to use `setTimeout` in component's lifecycle, but in my case I don't want to setTimeout if the component was mounted. I would like to trigger it it's after `calculateWinner()` returns a truthy value.

Is it possible to achieve something like this in react or in order to do so should I restructure my app/components architecture?

Heres' my example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6l607x80r

Most of the stuff is happening in `Board` component, where I've created a  `countDown()` function, but I'm not sure how to trigger it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle like this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (calculateWinner(this.state.squares)) {
    this.countDown();
  }
}
```

also, you will need to change your `countDown` function:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      xIsNext: true,
    })
  }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you setTimeout first argument needs to be a function and so you would write

```
countDown() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      xIsNext: true,
    }), 3000);
  }
```

Secondly, since you are calculating winner in render function, you would add another state variable to keep track of the countdown and then trigger countdown in render like

```
const winner = calculateWinner(this.state.squares);
let status;
if(winner && !this.state.isCounting) {
  this.countDown();
}
```

and countdown will look like

```
countDown() {
    this.setState({isCounting: true});
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      xIsNext: true,
      isCounting: false
    }), 3000);
  }
```

**[Working demo](http://%20https://codesandbox.io/s/k31l869mwr)**

Comment: I don't think it's good practice to change state in render function, it should be done for example in `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle

Comment: yup, react complained about that in the console.

Comment: Sure componentDidUpdate is better place

Answer (score 0):

So far I've come up two ways to do it.

Changing the countdown function to bind to (this) and then putting a return in the if(winner) statement that contains the html and the timer.

```
countDown()
{
    setTimeout
    (
        function()
        {
            this.setState
            ({
                squares : Array(9).fill(null),
                xIsNext : true,
/*//old----------------------------------------------------------------
            }),
            3000
        );
*///-------------------------------------------------------------------
            });
        }
        .bind(this),
        3000
    );
}
```

And I changed the if winner to this.

```
if(winner)
{
    status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
// Old code doesn't contain a return here.-----------------------------
    return(
            <div>
                <div className="status">{status}</div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(0)}
                    {this.renderSquare(1)}
                    {this.renderSquare(2)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(3)}
                    {this.renderSquare(4)}
                    {this.renderSquare(5)}
                </div>
                <div style={{ marginBottom: 30 }} className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(6)}
                    {this.renderSquare(7)}
                    {this.renderSquare(8)}
                </div>
                <Button id="reset" onClick={this.reset}>
                    Reset
                </Button>
// Call counDown(this) after the button.-------------------------------
                {this.countDown(this)}
            </div>
    )
}
else
{
    status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
}
```

The other way I was able to get it to work was to add setTimeout() in if(winner)

```
if(winner)
{
    status = "Winner: " + winner;
// Just add setTimeout() and it will reset after 3 seconds.------------
    setTimeout
    (
        ()=>
        {
            this.setState
            ({
                squares : Array(9).fill(null),
                xIsNext : true
            });
        },
        3000
    );
}
else
{
    status = "Next player: " + (this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
}
```

Here is an [EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/mqqj4my0o9)

I've been playing with getting a countdown timer to display and will add it if I get it done later.